# Linux Image to recreate a machine with the same configuration

Tags: linux, centos, openstack

I have a CentOS 6.5  machine with some installed packages , I want three more identical boxes to be setup and I was wondering if I can make an image of the one machine that I have pre-configured and use that image to make copies of that one machine onto other machines.

This would save me a lot of time, please let me know if this is possible ?

Would OpenStack be an option here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Offtopic here on SO (try superuser.com), but yes that's quite possible, check out clonezilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [clonzilla](http://clonezilla.org/). It is used take image of existing os. You can use those images to recreate the system.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that , what about openstack, does it help in installation or monitoring , how is it different from clonezilla ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't worked with openstack.